# hidden_field_tag fails to pass boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean, hidden-field, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-2.5

I am passing a hidden field for a form to distinguish between views the request came from:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag("advanced", true)%>
```

Apparently true gets passed as a string. I tried different syntaxes like:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "advanced", true %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "advanced" => true %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :advanced => true %>
```

It always gets translated to this

```
<input type="hidden" name="advanced" id="advanced" value="true" />
```

Obviously, I can check the string value in the controller, but is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails translate your parameters to the equivalent html, and it is only possible to have strings in html. The `hidden_field_tag` is just a hidden `text_field_tag`, so the value need to be text. And in the url you also have a string. So the conversion need to be done in the controller.